# SAML2.0 Assertion for html5/js based app deployed to tomcat 8.0

Tags: javascript, html, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, tomcat8

We have a requirement to configure SSO for a html5/js based Web App that is going to run on Tomcat 8.0. Could someone point me in the right direction to proceed..

We have our own IdP for our organisation and all I need to know is how to make our app get authenticated using the IdP. I know Tomcat 8.0 has a SingleSignOn valve , but I am not sure how to make use of it.. Your help is highly appreciated.. !!

Answer (score 0):

Using SAML2 directly from JavaScript is non-trivial. The SAML2 specification is from an era before JavaScript was used to build full applications.

A common way to bridge the gap is to use OpenID Connect from Javascript based applications. In some cases the Idp has support for that protocol too. In other cases, an intermediate identity provider is used that acts as an OpenID Connect Provider and as a SAML2 SP towards the SAML2 Idp.